# How to copy a text without loosing it applied style in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

As seen in this screenshot, I have text in many formats with their applied font styles, and I've developed a copy text method in list tile with every font, but the problem is that when I copy the text, it gives me plaintext instead of their applied font Style text, assume you applied bold text like '**example_text**', however when you copy and paste it, you will obtain plaintext 'example_text' instead of the applied style.

[image: Demo Image]

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Font Styles Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const FontStylesScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FontStylesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FontStylesScreen({Key? key});

  @override
  _FontStylesScreenState createState() => _FontStylesScreenState();
}

class _FontStylesScreenState extends State<FontStylesScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> _fontFamilies = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getAvailableFonts();
  }

  void _getAvailableFonts() {
    final fonts = GoogleFonts.asMap().keys.toList();
    setState(() {
      _fontFamilies = fonts;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Font Styles Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter Text',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              ),
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _fontFamilies.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    _textController.text,
                    style: GoogleFonts.getFont(_fontFamilies[index], fontSize: 30),
                  ),
                  trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.copy),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      // Convert text to UTF bytes
                      List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(_textController.text);
                      // Set UTF bytes to clipboard
                      Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(
                        text: utf8.decode(bytes),
                        // Ensure that the clipboard data is in UTF-8 format
                      ));
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Copied to clipboard'),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to paste it inside the app, right? Because it not possible to paste the same fonts and styles out side the app.

And FYI - Clipboard do not support the font styles.

It depends on where you paste it.

Here in the flutter - you can copy a JSON object -
{"Text":"Demo text", "fontStyle":"Cursue"}.

Comment: i want to paste it outside the app as well, also i've tried with JSON object but i won't find anything useful from it, it only gives me JSON. if you have any other method to achieve this so i would like to try that.

Comment: @DhobiDhruv its not possible to paste the text with the same theme outside the app.
Because different platforms(React native, flutter, android) uses different kinds of fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You Can try Adding Different **package** called **"extended_clipboard"** for copying the Text and also Other Text Format. Also you Can see more details and features in pub.dev

Comment: I'm not able to find that package in pub dev could you pls share that package link as well.

Comment: may be the package name had been changed but you can use "super_clipboard" which is available in pub.dev at https://pub.dev/packages/super_clipboard or another is "rich_clipboard"  => https://pub.dev/packages/rich_clipboard

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).